# update multiple user meta field based on another meta field

Tags: database, users, user-meta

I have a user meta field called "user_status" and another called "user_profile_id". The user profile ID is a unique field which is managed manually. It's a 4 digit number. The user_status field is simply a 1 or 0 if the user is online or not.

I have an XML feed which contains a list of the user_profile_id and their status (1 or 0). I can get the XML in to an array and loop through to display each user_profile_id and it's associated status.

However, I cannot get my head around how to update each user's status in the database. I have an array which looks like this:

```
//online $users_online
Array
(
    [0] => 1122
    [1] => 3678
    [2] => 8872
)

//offline $users_offline
Array
(
    [0] => 3342
    [1] => 5784
)
```

I wanted to simply call the WPDB class to do an `"update users set user_status = 1 where user_profile_id IN ($online_array)"` sort of statement.

I've looked at the meta_query but that doesn't seem to be what I'm after.

The easiest way would be as I loop through the XML feed results, get that user_profile_id and run an individual update for that user... then move on to the next one. However this is being called every 20 seconds or so and if we have hundreds of users, that's a fair strain on the database!

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to process this? I'm at a loss!!

Comment: To be clear, you're saying the profile ID and online status are determined by an external service? And that external service generates the XML feed, which you wish to consume in order to update WordPress user data for the users associated with those detailed in the XML feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern regarding updating every relevant user row every 20 seconds or so is totally valid. One solution, then, is to store this data in a single row rather than using the metadata APIs or custom SQL to associate the data with each individual user. The [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) as well as the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) are both well suited to this task.

Using the Transients API provides a few additional benefits - in using an expiration time you could easily throttle the updates (i.e. even though you parse the XML 3 times a minute, you could update online status once a minute) and - perhaps more importantly - if you use a caching plugin on your site, the plugin may support keeping transient data in memory in between requests, further reducing database interactions.

As the 4 digit profile ID serves as identifying information associated with a single WordPress user and is unlikely to change frequently, it is best if the profile ID is still stored as user meta-data. Given that online/offline status is a binary state (users must be one or the other), you can get by storing just one of your arrays - i.e. if a user is in the array, they are online. If not, they are offline.

Which data you store in the transient is somewhat dependent on your application. Storing WordPress user IDs seems somewhat unreasonable, as it means you'd be running a user query to determine which WordPress IDs compose your the "online list" every time you update the list. Rather, simply storing the array of user profile IDs with online status may be more performant - when you need to display a user's online status, use the meta-data API to acquire their profile ID, and then simply check whether or not that profile ID is in your "profiles online" transient. If you need a list of WordPress users with online status, run a user query with a meta-query to find users with profile IDs contained in the transient.

As a final note, don't update the transient data every time you parse the XML. Instead, create your array of online profiles from the XML data, then use two calls to `array_diff()` compare the elements in the XML-produced array against the one in transient data. If either resulting array has a length greater than `0`, the "online list" has changed, and you should update the transient. This will save several more potential database interactions.